# How can I enable Visual Effects on Ubuntu 10 running on VMware Player on Windows 7?

Tags: vmware, effects

I am running Ubuntu 10 on a VMware player running on Windows 7.
I have an Geforce 8800 card.

Currently I can't run visual effects, and I wasn't able to find any answer except for changing the VM to VirtualBox.
Since I already use VMWare for other purposes, I don't want to use VirtualBox.

Is there a way to enable Visual Effects and stay in VMWare?

Thanks,
Sakin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing, but VM Player doesn't support visual effects at all, which is pretty much the one big 'damn' I've come across comparing VMP & VB